# A singleton class to design a generic deck of card?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm reading the famous cracking the coding interview book and I'm now in a chapter about OOD (Object Oriented Design) with this problem :

> design the data structures for a generic deck of cards. Explain how you would subclass the data structures to implement blackjack.

I want to show you here a code that I didn't understand well :

```
public enum Suit { 
    Club (0),
    Diamond (1),
    Heart (2),
    Spade (3);

    private int value;
    private Suit(int v) {
    value = v;
    }

    public int getValue() {
    return value;
    }

    public static Suit getSuitFromValue(int value) {
    switch (value) {
    case 0:
        return Suit.Club;
    case 1:
        return Suit.Diamond;
    case 2:
        return Suit.Heart;
    case 3: 
        return Suit.Spade;
    default:
            return null;
    }
   }
  }
```

I'm discovering know the design patterns and I met some difficulties to recognize them in codes. But, when we see a private constructor like in this example, it **absolutely** means  that we want to implement the singleton pattern to have an unique instance of this class, no? Which I found logical, because in one Deck, we have only one suit of each type (diamond, heart...).

So, **if** (I don't know if there is another cases when the constructor is private), this class is a singleton :

- Why the value is only private int and not private static int??
- Why there is no "new " operator in that class? We should at least instanciate a suite to be able to use it no? So, we should have something like : return new Suit.Heart; if (hear !=null)
- I think it's a BIG problem if a singleton class isn't thread safe no? Because we have to do something to deal with two threads access to the class at the same time. Something like eager instanciation or Double-checked locking with volatile keyword and synchronized only for the first instanciation... I mean, there is many technics to do that, but if we do nothing for that, it can become very bad in term of OOD and performance, no?

Thank you if you can help me to understand better these points

Comment: Why do you think a singleton would be a good design for a deck of cards? I'm pretty sure there is more than one deck of cards in the world...

Comment: if you take a closer look, you will see this is actually enum and not a class, this should solve most of the mysteries for you- it means it has private constructor because it is enum and not because it is a singleton, constructors are called without the 'new' keyword because of the same reason and the value cant be static because you 4 different enum constants with different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are different than Classes in Java.  They have special uses that are more restrictive than Classes.

The reason the constructor is private in an Enum is because the value associated with the instance is supposed to be predefined. Enums are useful when you need to represent a fixed set of constants like the days of the week for example.  You can define the values at compile time and just refer to them by name (MONDAY, TUESDAY, etc.).

If the constructor were public, someone using your code could potentially invent their own Suit at run time. That would certainly break the standard rules of Blackjack and cause errors to anyone playing.

Assigning the values to Suits at compile time increases compile-time checking, avoids errors from passing in invalid constants, and also documents the allowed values.

The static method in your example is a convenience utility to convert an integer to it's corresponding Suit but isn't a requirement for an Enum.

The above class is thread safe and the creation of Enums are thread safe because they are initialized when the Enum is "class-loaded" by the JVM but you can still create methods in Enums which are not thread-safe.